# How to I revert to manual save mode

Tags: google-app-maker

In app maker where on a table do I set and reset manual save mode after the table has been created on the page?

I have tried look at the API documentation, and while it talks to Manual Save Mode. It does not have a method to call, that I can see, to toggle this.

Comment: So, you want to toggle manual save mode while the application is running? Or is it fine to turn it on before running the application?

Comment: Why do you need to toggle 'save mode' in runtime?

Comment: Thank you. I want to change it at design time. But it seems that it is global and sticky. I.e. once I have set and used it once (at design time) I can not seem to find a way to change the save mode.

Answer (score 0):

'Save mode' is design time setting and cannot be changed in runtime.

You can toggle 'Manual save mode' check box for any datasource(only for editable models) any time while designing your app:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I want to change it at **design time**. But it seems that it is global and sticky. I.e. once I have set and used it once (at design time) I can not seem to find a way to change the save mode.

Comment: I've added instructions hot to toggle save mode in designer.